# Change Gnome terminal theme programmatically

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to create a setup on my local machine (Ubuntu GNOME)  whereby the terminal window has a different background color depending on whether I'm logged in to my local machine or ssh'd into a remote machine.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would also welcome any suggestions on how to better organise my clutter of terminal windows and tabs from the Gnome terminal. Nice question.

Comment: Use a better window-manager. A tiling one maybe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't do what you asked for, but it probably does what you want.

You can modify your `.bashrc` (or equivalent shell init file) to set your prompt based on whether you're using ssh or not.

i.e. put something like:

```
if [ -n $SSH_TTY ]; then
     export PS1=`echo -en '\033[42m\w\$ '`;
fi;
```

at the end of your `.bashrc` file on the remote machine.  the `\033[42m` is an [ANSI Escape Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that changes the background colour to green.

This way, the background colour of your terminal will be green (or magenta, or cyan, or whatever) *only* when you're logged in to a remote machine.

Comment: Seemingly a good idea but not working in all cases, background is black again in Vim, on ls -l output.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to checkout the options to gnome-terminal:

```
gnome-terminal --help
```

gives

```
 --window-with-profile=PROFILENAME
```

Wrap this in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=PROFILENAME
```

then do

```
ssh-term
```

If you want to change more, look into aterm and other terms. Also look into Devilspie which can do more dynamic changes based on things like window title (removing window decorations and so on).

Comment: This requires you to open a new window with the specific intent to use it to SSH, and to close it immediately after the SSH connection is closed - otherwise it is misleading and worse than nothing. Not exactly an elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [GConf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GConf). It basically is for Gnome what The Registry is for Windows. Most Gnome apps use it to store their settings. You can browse it using tools like [GConf-Editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gconf-editor), or from the command line using `gconftool-2`:

```
$ gconftool-2 --all-entries /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default
background_color = #000000000000
palette = #2E2E34343636:#CCCC00000000 [ snipped ]
... many more lines
```

You will find all settings here that are accessible via the Preferences dialog, plus some more. Keys can also be changed using `--set`, see "`man gconftool-2`" for details.

There are also GConf library bindings for many programming languages.

Comment: Almost what I need, but it changes the "global" registry.... not the current tab only. I could set up themes for different machines, but I need a way to switch this via a command

Answer (score 3):

I have some scripts which achieve this purpose for gnome-terminal. You can find them at https://github.com/xyrix/gnome-terminal-profile-switcher

The script works by creating a temporary profile for all terminals, and then changing the values set in the temporary profile to be copied from your normal profiles.

This allows you to change the profile of the current gnome-terminal from a script.

Included in the repository is an example "safe_ssh" script to demonstrate the usage.

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu Gnome, I use .desktop files to create ssh logins with different terminal colours.

The Terminal colour can be setup on gnome-terminal in the Profiles section. I create a different profile for each background colour that I use.

I create a .desktop file shortcut for each of the server's ssh logins and put these into ~/.local/share/applications/ so that they show up in Gnome's Applications overview.

Here's an example .desktop file for ssh'ing into the localhost as root. The profile is called Red, and is configured with a red background using gnome-terminal's profile settings.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_GB]=gksu-root-terminal
Name[en_GB]=LOCALHOST Root
Exec=gnome-terminal --window-with-profile Red --command "ssh -XC root@localhost"
Name=LOCALHOST Root
Icon=gksu-root-terminal
```

Here's an example of a multiple ssh to a server which opens a tabbed terminal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_GB]=gnome-terminal
Name[en_GB]=MYREMOTESERVER Root
Exec=gnome-terminal --command='ssh -XC root@MYREMOTESERVER'  --window-with-profile Blue --tab-with-profile Blue --tab-with-profile Blue --tab-with-profile Blue --tab-with-profile Blue  --hide-menubar 
Name=MYREMOTESERVER Root
Icon=gnome-terminal
```

The server is MYREMOTESERVER  and the profile being used is called Blue.

This technique also works with the KDE desktop. The desktop shortcuts end up in the lost and found folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
```